# Filtering checkboxes selection

Tags: jquery

I have a container which contains divs of the same format. Each div has 3 attributes in which I am applying filter options to.

the div looks like this

`<div data-A="1" data-B="x" data-C="4"`>

Each of the 3 options, A B and C has values for each option. 
For example A has values 1 2 3, B has values x y z, C has values 4 5 6. They are available as checkboxes like this

So if I checked an A option with value = 1, the div that has data-A = 1 will show, so if I checked A option with value = 1, B option with value = x and C option with value = z, divs that fulfil these 3 values will be shown.

However, how do I actually cater to situations in which one of the A,B and C is not chosen as a filter at all, ie checked B option with value = x and C option with value = 4, so I should be showing all divs with data-B = 'x' and data-C = '4'.

right now, I am using 3 nested for loops for this, which will not cater to the situation in which one option is not chosen. Is there any way to do this efficiently?

My jquery for now is as below

```
for(var p = 0;p < $(A).length ;p++)
    {
        for(var q = 0;q < $(B).length ;q++)
        {
            for(var r = 0;r < $(C).length ;r++)
            {
                $('div[data-A = "'+ A[p] + '"][data-B="'+ B[q] +'"][data-C="'+ C[r] +'"]').show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I assume that given the fact that they're checkboxes, you can have multiple value of either A,B and C checked at the same time? In which case you'll show every matching div? And what are exaclty `$(A)`/`$(B)`/`$(C)`? Are they the checked checkbox?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarification. Yes I can have multiple values of either A ,B and C checked $(A) /$(B) /$(C) are the checked checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

The way I would go about that, is to listen to the overall change and switch the display accordingly to the last checkbox that's been changed.

Something along the lines:

```
/*Put whatever is needed to select your checkboxes of the A family here*/
$("input[type='checkbox'].A").on("change", function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        $("div[data-A='" + this.value + "']").each(function(index, elt) {
            /*This is pseudo code, you'll need to put here a way to select the correct checkbox and to check if it's checked*/
            if ($(elt).data("B").isChecked && $(elt).data("C").isChecked) {
                $(elt).show();
            } else {
                $(elt).hide();
            }
        }
    } else {
        $("div[data-A='" + this.value + "']").hide()
    }
});
```

You can either make a separate function for every `data-X` or factorize it a bit to avoid redundancy.